# Foundation 2010 Services fail to restart on reboot

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-foundation, deployment

All of the services on our SP Install that use Domain Accounts fail to start automatically after an IIS Restart or System Restart.

**Services Affected:**

SharePoint 2010 Timer - Logging on as "xyzdomain\SharepointServicesAccount"

SharePoint 2010 User Code Host - Logging on as "xyzdomain\SharepointGeneralAccount"

SharePoint Foundation Search V4 - Loggin on as "xyzdomain\SharepointGeneralAccount"

When trying to start the services manually, I am getting an "Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure".

I have verified that both of the accounts have "logon as a service" rights in Active Directory.

**Attempted Resolution:**

If I go and add their "logon as a service" rights back using the "local security policy" snap-in, I am able to reboot the machine once before I lose the settings again.

Does anyone have any idea why this right is being erased from these accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check with your domain admins to make sure they don't have a policy that is being pushed down that is overwriting the local policy.